# How to represent class instances in UML?

Tags: uml, class-diagram, object-diagram

I have a class diagram for my application which consists of several compositions and aggregations.

Now I want to have diagram based on the class diagram which shows class instances. A snapshot if you will. I need this because it would help discussing some functional requirements.

**Class diagram**:

```
 --------   1                 *  ------- 
| Parent |----------------------| Child |
 --------                        -------
```

**"Instance" diagram**:

```
 --------                        --------- 
| Parent |----------------------| Child 1 |
 --------           |            ---------
                    |
                    |            ---------
                    +-----------| Child 2 |
                    |            ---------
                    |
                    |            ---------
                    +-----------| Child 3 |
                                 ---------
```

Is there a diagram type for this? (Currently I'm mis-using a class diagram, where all my instances are separate classes)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Use [Object diagram](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/31863#object-diagrams) or
- Use keyword <<[instance](http://hcs.science.uva.nl/usr/Schreiber/docs/owl-uml/owl-uml.html)>> or
- [Underline class name](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rsmhelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xtools.modeler.doc/topics/cinstancespec.html)

Comment: Object diagram likely most appropriate as, from original q, an objective is to illustrate relationship cardinality.

Comment: Unfortunately the last two links are dead.

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20140523210656/http://hcs.science.uva.nl/usr/Schreiber/docs/owl-uml/owl-uml.html

Answer (score 3):

An "instance" diagram in UML is called an Object Diagram.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Object Diagram" as *Peter G. McDonald* said.

See the wiki :[Object Diagram Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_diagram)
In UML if what you want doesn't exist you can adapt classic Diagram for what you want
  something just like you did but with comment block to explain your choices
Documentation is as important as diagrams.

If you want to describe the life cycle of yours instances you can use 
"State machine diagram".