# How to represent Ontology instance in ArgoUML class diagram

Tags: class, instance, ontology, class-diagram, argouml

I am developing ontology using ArgoUML class diagram and I want to show some instances of classes. Is there a way in ArgoUML to do this?

Thanks for your helps in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

If you're wedded to using a Class diagram, something like an `<<instance>>` stereotype is probably the easiest choice.  Otherwise you can use a Deployment Diagram (ArgoUML's version of an Object Diagram).

Both suggestions from here: [How to represent class instances in UML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202970/how-to-represent-class-instances-in-uml)